# How can I inform my facebook app users when I publish new articles in my site

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an article site. I have created an app for the article site. Now I would like to inform the users of my app , when I publish new articles in my site . Which is the best method? Post to their wall ?, Then how can I do that , please help me . Now I can post to the users wall, when they write a review. But now I am trying to inform them about new article arrival.

Plz help me ,

Thanks in advance

Sunil

Comment: You can publish on there wall,but in that case may be it happens that some user have privacy so that u cannot post on their wall, second option is you can send then notification about new article

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. How can I post to a user wall with out any action from the user. I mean I would like to post to his wall , even he is not logged in..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I would like to inform the users of my app , when I publish new articles in my site . Which is the best method?

Create a fan page on Facebook, and post your updates there. Then the users who liked your page will see your updates in their feeds.

> Post to their wall ?

That might be considered spam by many users; you should only do such a thing after explicit opt-in by the user.